# Magento 2.3.3 Email Issue When Sending Email copy to multiple email

Tags: magento, magento2

I am facing issue in the email in magento2. this issue is only faced in Magento 2.3.3.

**How to produce**

Go to
   **Store-> Configuration-> Sales-> Sales Emails -> Send Order Email Copy To   -> enter multiple comma separated emails**.

and change **Send Order Email Copy Method** BCC to separate Email

Now open any order and click on send an email you will get an error in

**TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Email\Model\Template\Interceptor::setVars() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php on line 368**

have any one faced or fixed it??

Comment: hi.. i found a fix for it.

  vendor/magento/module-sales/model/order/email/SenderBuilder.php

  $copyTo = $this->identityContainer->getEmailCopyTo();
      if (!empty($copyTo)) {
      cut from here ->     $this->configureEmailTemplate();
         foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
      paste here ->       ** $this->configureEmailTemplate();**
                $this->transportBuilder->addTo($email);
                $transport = $this->transportBuilder->getTransport();
                $transport->sendMessage();

please up vote if its work for you

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/24855/files/dbf2c29bef8ec4a768156bd7ace0c99647bec631

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix for it.

> vendor/magento/module-sales/model/order/email/SenderBuilder.php

```
if (!empty($copyTo)) {
            $this->configureEmailTemplate();
            foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
                $this->transportBuilder->addTo($email);
                $transport = $this->transportBuilder->getTransport();
                $transport->sendMessage();
```

replace above code as below

```
if (!empty($copyTo)) {
            foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
                $this->configureEmailTemplate();
                $this->transportBuilder->addTo($email);
                $transport = $this->transportBuilder->getTransport();
                $transport->sendMessage();
```

Note: please dont do code in core file.

Comment: how do you override this code without touching vendor files?

Comment: ``<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Email\Sender\OrderSender"/>``

Comment: If you want detailed answer then ask another question. I can't able to add answer here. but it's core issue and I think fixed in next release so you can add fix in vendor file. ``still add a code in vendor is not recommanded``